# Animation suddenly jumps when padding is set on an element

Tags: javascript, css, animation, ecmascript-6, animateplus

In an accordion animated with [`Animate Plus`](https://github.com/bendc/animateplus), when `padding` is set on an element, the collapsing animation suddenly jumps when closing…

[image: jumping animation]

The animation is smooth when `padding` is not set…

[image: smooth animation]

How can I smoothly animate the accordion when `padding` is set?

My JavaScript code:

```js
const accordions = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("dl")).map(dl => ({
  element: dl,
  translate: 0
}))

const getButtons = accordion =>
  Array.from(accordion.element.getElementsByTagName("button"), element => ({
    element,
    translate: 0
  }))

const timing = {
  easing: "out-quartic",
  duration: 400
}

const clear = element =>
  Object.values(element.attributes).forEach(({ name }) =>
    element.removeAttribute(name)
  )

const hide = async (accordion, buttons, collapsing) => {
  const objects = buttons.filter(({ translate }) => translate)
  const direction = "reverse"
  rotate(collapsing.previousElementSibling.lastElementChild, direction)
  slide(accordion, objects)
  await fold(collapsing, direction)
  clear(collapsing)
}

const show = (accordion, buttons, expanding) => {
  const button = expanding.previousElementSibling.lastElementChild
  const index = buttons.findIndex(({ element }) => element == button)
  const objects = buttons.slice(index + 1)
  const { height } = expanding.getBoundingClientRect()
  expanding.className = "open"
  rotate(button)
  slide(accordion, objects, height)
  fold(expanding)
}

const slide = (accordion, array, to = 0) => {
  center(accordion, to)
  animate({
    ...timing,
    elements: array.map(({ element }) => element.parentElement),
    transform(index) {
      const object = array[index]
      const from = object.translate
      object.translate = to
      return [`translateY(${from}px)`, to]
    }
  })
}

const center = (accordion, height) => {
  const from = accordion.translate
  const to = Math.round(-height / 2)
  accordion.translate = to
  animate({
    ...timing,
    elements: accordion.element,
    transform: [`translateY(${from}px)`, to]
  })
}

const fold = async (content, direction = "normal") => {
  const scrollHeight = content.scrollHeight
  await animate({
    ...timing,
    direction,
    elements: content,
    opacity: [0, 1],
    maxHeight: ["0px", scrollHeight + "px"],
    transform: ["scaleY(0)", 1]
  })
}
const rotate = ({ lastElementChild: elements }, direction = "normal") =>
  animate({
    elements,
    direction,
    easing: "out-cubic",
    duration: 600,
    transform: ["rotate(0turn)", 0.5]
  })

const toggle = (accordion, buttons) => async ({ target }) => {
  const collapsing = accordion.element.querySelector(".open")
  const expanding = target.parentElement.nextElementSibling
  if (collapsing) await hide(accordion, buttons, collapsing)
  if (collapsing != expanding) show(accordion, buttons, expanding)
}

accordions.forEach(accordion => {
  const buttons = getButtons(accordion)
  buttons.forEach(({ element }) =>
    element.addEventListener("click", toggle(accordion, buttons))
  )
})

import animate from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animateplus@2/animateplus.js"
```

> My full code for an accordion can be found on CodePen:
>
> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJjYba

Comment: Perhaps try your own css animation that runs concurrently with the Animate Plus animation: transition: padding duration of Animation Plus animation;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to add `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` to the `fold` function :

```
const fold = async (content, direction = "normal") => {
  const scrollHeight = content.scrollHeight
    await animate({
        ...timing,
        direction,
        elements: content,
        opacity: [0, 1],
        maxHeight: ['0px', scrollHeight + 'px'],
        transform: ["scaleY(0)", 1],
        paddingTop: ['0em', '2em'], // add this
        paddingBottom: ['0em', '2em'] // add this
    })
}
```

[Code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jdjowa)

Comment: Check that on subsequent toggles (more than just a single open/close).

Comment: @ItoPizarro i see what you mean, that's another issue, not cause by the solution, it happens without it too.

Comment: Your change to the `timing.duration` is affecting the timing of concurrent/sequential animations. I arrived at essentially the same solution but left the timing as-is, and it doesn't exhibit that value compounding behavior.

Comment: @ItoPizarro oh, i did that while debugging, i forgot to remove it,it's not mentionned in the snippet in the answer so it's not suppoed to be a part of it,  i updated the Pen, thnx for spotting it.

Answer (score 1):

Animate the padding in the `fold()` method; add your desired measurements to `paddingBottom` and `paddingTop` properties. Then, you can remove the padding property from the `.open` class rule in the CSS.

```
const fold = async (content, direction = "normal") => {
  const scrollHeight = content.scrollHeight;
  await animate({
    ...timing,
    direction,
    elements: content,
    opacity: [0, 1],
    maxHeight: ["0px", scrollHeight + "px"],
    paddingTop: ["0em", "2em"],
    paddingBottom: ["0em", "2em"],
    transform: ["scaleY(0)", 1]
  });
};
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/itopizarro/pen/PVrrea)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the padding to a new child element. So, wrap the content in an extra `div` like this:

```
<dd><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div></dd>
```

And then, instead of styling `.open` style the `div` inside:

```
.open div {
    padding: 2em 0;
}
```

It doesn't jump using the child.